# Counting values in a range

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the number of employees with a salary in a certain range. How can I output the number just for the 'Salary' column.

```
salaryEmp = data4[data4.Salary.between(100, 500)].count()
```

Comment: I'm confused about that code sample.  Does it work?  If not, what does it do?

Comment: Yes it does, and it lists all the columns, and outputs the number next to each column

Comment: What do you mean it "outputs the number next to each column"?  I don't see any `print` statement in that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `value_counts`

```
data4.Salary.value_counts(bins=[100,500])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
df.loc[df.Salary.between(100,500), 'Salary'].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

`len(data4[(data4.Salary>100) & (data4.Salary<500)])`

Comment: using pure-python `sum` is not optimal here, will be very slow since it iterates through the values. Also, your solution only works if you only have one column. If you have more than two, this will yield either an error or the wrong answer

Comment: You may keep the sum, just use `data4.loc[(data4.Salary>100) & (data4.Salary<500), 'Salary'].sum()` i.e. use pandas vectorized `sum()` at the end